# arduino 3 dimension string array

Tags: arrays, 3d, arduino

i would like to know if i can use a 3 dimensional array of strings in arduino code. i want to change java code to arduino.

public static String[][][] turn(String rot, String anaptigma[][][]){

```
    String a, b, c;

    if (rot=="rt") {                                        //right
        a=anaptigma[0][0][2];
        b=anaptigma[0][1][2];
        c=anaptigma[0][2][2];

        anaptigma[0][0][2]=anaptigma[2][0][2];
        anaptigma[0][1][2]=anaptigma[2][1][2];
        anaptigma[0][2][2]=anaptigma[2][2][2];
        anaptigma[2][0][2]=anaptigma[4][0][2];
        anaptigma[2][1][2]=anaptigma[4][1][2];
        anaptigma[2][2][2]=anaptigma[4][2][2];
        anaptigma[4][0][2]=anaptigma[5][0][2];
        anaptigma[4][1][2]=anaptigma[5][1][2];
        anaptigma[4][2][2]=anaptigma[5][2][2];
        anaptigma[5][0][2]=a;
        anaptigma[5][1][2]=b;
        anaptigma[5][2][2]=c;

        a=anaptigma[3][0][0];
        b=anaptigma[3][0][1];
        c=anaptigma[3][0][2];
        anaptigma[3][0][0]=anaptigma[3][2][0];
        anaptigma[3][0][1]=anaptigma[3][1][0];
        anaptigma[3][0][2]=a;
        anaptigma[3][2][0]=anaptigma[3][2][2];
        anaptigma[3][1][0]=anaptigma[3][2][1];  
        anaptigma[3][2][1]=anaptigma[3][1][2];  
        anaptigma[3][1][2]=b;
```

this is a small sample

Comment: Yes you can.  Did you have a more specific question?

Comment: i would like to know what can i do to return the modified array from function to my main loop. i am also having problems on declaring my array

Answer (score 0):

you can simply pass the array like the example below.

```
void setupArray(String arr[][3][4])
{
    arr[0][0][0] = "Hello";  
    arr[1][2][3] = "World";
}  

void setup() 
{
   Serial.begin(9600);

   String myArray[2][3][4];
   setupArray(myArray);
   Serial.println(myArray[0][0][0] + " " + myArray[1][2][3]);
}
```

Anyway, you probably need to take care of memory usage since usually Java runs on much less constrained environments (when compared to a typical Arduino board which usually has few kilobytes of memory)

Comment: int turn(int rot,int anaptigma[6][3][3]){
  
bla bla bla
  
return turn;
 }
basically my main problem is these lines of code.
i cant return my array from function. 
i get an error like this

try1.ino: In function 'int turn(int, int (*)[3][3])':
try1:460: error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)[3][3]' to 'int'  
any other ideas?